# Binding a class list to xaml doesnt work (I am trying to use MVVM for a WPF)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

The Binding is unsuccsesfull and I am not sure as to why

I tried to bind as shown in the code below but it was unsuccsesfull
(no error or exeption thrown just didnt work)
It shows NoDataContext found when hovering over Items in the Xaml, however the sugested Fix(adding: "xmlns:viewmoddel="clr-namespace:WpfApp3.ViewModdel" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmoddel:MainWindowViewModdel})" doesnt work as well, it trows the exeption :"Items not accessible

the Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
        xmlns:ScottPlot="clr-namespace:ScottPlot;assembly=ScottPlot.WPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="MaxAufProg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="27,392,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" RenderTransformOrigin="0.389,-6.576"/>
        <DataGrid 
            ItemsSource = "{Binding Items}"
            SelectedItem = "{Binding SelectedItem}"
            CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Typ" Binding="{Binding type}" Width="4*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Funktioniert" Binding="{Binding works}" Width="3*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kapput" Binding="{Binding doesntwork}" Width="3*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unbekant" Binding="{Binding mightwork}" Width="3*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>


        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

the Code Behind

```
using System.Windows;
using WpfApp3.ViewModdel;
namespace WpfApp3
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainWindowViewModdel vm = new MainWindowViewModdel();
            DataContext = vm;
        }
    }
}
```

the ViewModel:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using WpfApp3.Moddel;
using WpfApp3.MVVM;

namespace WpfApp3.ViewModdel
{
    internal class MainWindowViewModdel : ViewModdelBase
    {
        ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public MainWindowViewModdel()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            Items.Add(new Item
            {
                type = "Staircase",
                works = 829,
                doesntwork = 131,
                mightwork = 42
            }) ;
            Items.Add(new Item
            {
                type = "Lift",
                works = 2356,
                doesntwork = 150,
                mightwork = 53
            });
        }
        private Item selectedItem;
        public Item SelectedItem
        {
            get { return selectedItem; }
            set 
            { 
                selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the ViewModdelBase

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApp3.MVVM
{
    internal class ViewModdelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

the Model:

```
namespace WpfApp3.Moddel
{
    internal class Item
    {
        public int works {  get; set; }
        public int doesntwork { get; set; }
        public int mightwork { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*Items not accessible*" is a correct error message. The Items property should be public.

Comment: As a note, it seems redundant to have three properties for the state of an item. A working state like yes/no/maybe should be modeled as a single property of some enum type. Also check spelling, correct would be "Kaputt" and "Unbekannt".